# sql to generate a column by manipulating previous row and previous column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following in a table

```
  c1   
  1  
  4  
  3  
  2  
  2
```

I need to generate c2 as:

```
 
  c1 c2  
  1  1
  4  5
  3  8
  2  10
  2  12
```

The first row of c2 is c1 row value. Now need to add c1's 2nd row and c2's first row for   c2's second row.For third row of c2, C2= c1's third + c2's second and so on...

I need this in sql. Is it possible?

I use oracle 11g.

Comment: You can do this with Analytic Functions - LEAD / LAG... I can help with that, but you need to be able to give it the order. Here is some background reading though! [link]http://www.orafaq.com/node/55

Comment: you can use NULL in the order by @Captain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm does just simplify to running total:

```
create table c2 as
select c1
, sum(c1) over (ORDER BY rowid) as c2
from c1;
```

The order is an issue - we can't `ORDER BY NULL`. I have used `rowid` given that your example doesn't order by `c1`. But if you are doing a running total, you must decided what it is running against!

Comment: can you tell me how this line works "over (ORDER BY rowid)" @captain.I could not get that how the data gets grouped there.

Comment: @theDbGuy - the OVER... tells Oracle that it is the "Analytic Function" SUM rather than the "normal" one... Analytic (also called Window functions outside Oracle!) compute an aggregate value based on a group of rows (called a window). For each data row, a sliding window is defined, giving the rows used to perform the calculation. The window size can be based on either a physical number of rows or a logical interval such as time. A good overview is at that link I gave: [link]http://www.orafaq.com/node/55